# Trouble using smoothScroll.js with a dynamic anchor and setTimout()

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm using [smooth-scroll.js](https://github.com/cferdinandi/smooth-scroll#readme) on my website, and I have an active javascript that creates an anchored link depending on the information entered into option tags. The problem I'm having is:

smoothScroll.init() is executing before the anchor link is initiated, so it just jumps to the link instead of smooth scrolling. I was thinking that using setTimeout() to delay the execution of smoothScroll.init(); would fix the problem, but it still isn't working.

Here's the link to the site. [Paper Inventory](http://www.primeinit.com/bluefrog/)

My goal is to get the site to smooth scroll to the correct paper DIV when the person clicks on the "Go To Paper" DIV. It should be simple, but because everything is dynamic, it's adding a bit more difficulty than I expected.

If you go to the site to test it, I suggest choosing United Trade Printers, 12x18, 100#, Accent Opaque, Smooth, White, Cover. I don't have an error message yet if you choose a paper that doesn't exist. So That's a good default one.

I'm also using jQuery, so jQuery answers are more than welcome, and would be easier to implement.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm in the exact same spot right now.